# Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed - MariaDB & Laravel

Tags: database, laravel, database-migration

I am running a databse migration in laravel 5.8 and I am getting the following error:

Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table `cartorque`.`likes` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed") (SQL: alter table `likes` add constraint `likes_
post_id_foreign` foreign key (`post_id`) references `posts` (`id`) on delete cascade on update cascade)

Here are how my tables are setup

```
User Table:
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

```
Posts Table
Schema::create('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->string('title', 500);
            $table->longText('content');
            $table->tinyInteger('privacy')->default('0');
            $table->string('location', 250);
            $table->bigInteger('longitude');
            $table->bigInteger('latitude');
            $table->bigInteger('user_id')->unsigned()->index();
            $table->string('slug', 250);
        });

        Schema::table('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')
                ->onDelete('cascade')
                ->onUpdate('cascade');
        });
```

```
Likes Table
Schema::create('likes', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('post_id');
            $table->boolean('like');
        });

        Schema::table('likes', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->foreign('post_id')->references('id')->on('posts')
                ->onDelete('cascade')
                ->onUpdate('cascade');
        });

        Schema::table('likes', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')
                ->onDelete('cascade')
                ->onUpdate('cascade');
        });
```

The Likes table is to have 2 foreign keys user_id and post_id. It works fine on user_id but I get the error on the post_id column

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue and it was the posts table not being created. This happened because the order of the migration files. The likes foreign key creation was occurring prior to the posts table being created. I change the order of the migration files.